# Javascript code broken

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, ide

This is my first attempt at a little more complex code structure. The thing is my IDE says it technically works , jsfiddle says it doesn't, it actually initializes only the two **confirm functions** that I declared "**confirmUserName();**"  and "**confirmFullName();**"

Can someone explain why i did such a horrible job.

```
var userList = [];  
var username = "";   
var fullname = ""; 
var addUserName = addUser(username, userList);        v
var addFullName = addUser(fullname, userList); 
function addUser(usrName, list) {
    if(list.length == 0) {
        list.push(usrName); // userlist empty add the new user
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {   
            if(list[i] == undefined) {            
                list[i] = usrName;              
                return list;                     
            } else if(i == list.length - 1) {    
                list.push(usrName);             
                return list;                   

            }
        }
    }
}            // Function that adds user and name to list

var usernameQuery;                                  
function confirmUserName() {
   confirm("Is " + username + " your first choice?");

    if (confirmUserName == true) {
        return fullnameQuery;
    } else {
        return usernameQuery;
    }
}                   
var fullnameQuery;                                   /
function fullnameConfirm() {
    confirm("Is " + fullname + " your first choice ");
    if (fullnameConfirm == true) {
        return  startRide;
    } else {
        return fullnameQuery;
    }
}                   
if(username == undefined) {
    usernameQuery = function() {
      username =  prompt("You are the first user to play, \n" +
               " Chose and let the game begin !");
      return addUserName;
    };
} else {
    usernameQuery = function() {
        username = prompt("What username whould you like to have ? \n" +
            " Chose and let the game begin !");
        return addUserName;
    };
}
confirmUserName();
if(fullname == undefined)  {
    fullnameQuery = function() {
        fullname = prompt("Enter your real name !");
        return addFullName;
    };

    } else {
    fullnameQuery = function() {
        fullname = prompt("Enter your real name!");
    return addFullName;

    };
}
fullnameConfirm();
```

Comment: "javascript code broken" ok... how? We're not going to run this into our browser to see what's wrong with it. What is wrong with it? What's the error? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: there's a V and a slash floating on your code. I haven't exactly taken a look at it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot wrong with the code you posted -- I'll just take one chunk:

```
function confirmUserName() {
   // The return value of `confirm` is ignored.
   confirm("Is " + username + " your first choice?");

    // confirmUserName is the name of your function.
    // You sould be using `===` instead of `==`
    // Or, not comparing against true at all.
    if (confirmUserName == true) {
        return fullnameQuery;
    } else {
        return usernameQuery;
    }
}
```

Fixed function:

```
function confirmUserName() {
   var res = confirm("Is " + username + " your first choice?");
    if (res) {
        return fullnameQuery;
    } else {
        return usernameQuery;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not throw Errors with this, but I dont know in which situation you want your code to be implemented and what it should do, I hope this is what you need:

```
var userList = [];
var username = "";
var fullname = "";
var addUserName = addUser(username, userList);

var addFullName = addUser(fullname, userList);

function addUser(usrName, list) {
    if (list.length === 0) {
        list.push(usrName); // userlist empty add the new user
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (list[i] === undefined) {
                list[i] = usrName;
                return list;
            } else if (i == list.length - 1) {
                list.push(usrName);
                return list;

            }
        }
    }
} // Function that adds user and name to list

var usernameQuery;

function confirmUserName() {
    confirm("Is " + username + " your first choice?");

    if (confirmUserName === true) {
        return fullnameQuery;
    } else {
        return usernameQuery;
    }
}
var fullnameQuery;

function fullnameConfirm() {
    confirm("Is " + fullname + " your first choice ");
    if (fullnameConfirm === true) {
        return startRide;
    } else {
        return fullnameQuery;
    }
}
if (username === undefined) {
    usernameQuery = function () {
        username = prompt("You are the first user to play, \n" +
            " Chose and let the game begin !");
        return addUserName;
    };
} else {
    usernameQuery = function () {
        username = prompt("What username whould you like to have ? \n" +
            " Chose and let the game begin !");
        return addUserName;
    };
}
confirmUserName();
if (fullname === undefined) {
    fullnameQuery = function () {
        fullname = prompt("Enter your real name !");
        return addFullName;
    };

} else {
    fullnameQuery = function () {
        fullname = prompt("Enter your real name!");
        return addFullName;

    };
}
fullnameConfirm();
```